# Is this a memory leak of angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

At http://docs.angularjs.org, click back and forth between pages the DOM Node Count continues to go up and up. No dramtical drop when I click "collect garbage".
[image]

I have opened an issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4864

Comment: I think no, the first assumption should be that it's an issue with the site, not with the framework the site is using.